# Prove Chebyshev's Inequality without using Markov's Inequility

Tags: probability, inequality

Recently I learnt both Markov's inequality and Chebyshev's Inequality, I know how to prove Markov's inequality and how to prove Chebyshev's Inequality, but then I was wondering if it is possible to prove Chebyshev's Inequality without using Markov's inequality, or it is fully relied on the Markov's inequality? Would appreciate if someone know the answer and show me the proof, thanks!

Comment: try applying the proof of Markov inequality you know to the random variable $(X-\mathbb E[X])^2$

Comment: How about using this fact: For a nonnegative random variable $Y$, we have $\mathbb{E}[Y] = \int_0^\infty \mathbb{P}(Y \ge t)\, \mathrm{d} t$.

Answer (score 1):

Lets define a random variable as:
\begin{cases} 
    \text{0} & \text{if $|X| \lt \epsilon$ }\\
    \text{$\epsilon$} & \text{if |X| $\geq \epsilon$}
\end{cases}
Lets denote it as Y. It is trivial that Y$\leq$|X| $\implies$ $Y^2 \leq X^2$ $\implies$ $\mathbb{E}(X^2)\geq \mathbb{E}(Y^2)=\epsilon^2\mathbb{P}(|X|\geq\epsilon)$, which implies the Chebyshev's Inequality.